# Vim: Vertical navigation in insert mode

Tags: vim, vimrc

I am using vim for quite some time but I think I broke my settings somehow after installing a few packages.

Let me show it with examples. In normal mode I am used to navigation like this:

[image: Normal mode]

However, when I switch to insert mode, my cursor doesn't remember it's original position anymore - note how it just keeps moving back. I am almost positive it acted differently before.

[image: Insert mode]

The most annoying thing is that it actually moves back again to fourth column when going to third line, even though I had my position at fifth column in second line, and fifth column is available in both lines.

So my question is: are there any settings that allow me to control this behavior in insert mode? My muscle memory is greatly suffering from this. I know of `:virtualedit=onemore` but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps you have mappings for the cursor keys.  Does `:map <Down>` show anything?

Comment: It's just bound to `gj`.

Comment: Then try `:iunmap <Down>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get where you are from a standard installation do:

```
:set virtualedit=insert
```

and the cursor behaviour will be what you describe.

To get back to what you were used to:

```
:set virtualedit=onemore
```

(you missed the ':set' part in what you describe above.

Having said that: there are many reasons for not navigating through a file with arrow keys in vim. See [this post on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737163/traversing-text-in-insert-mode) as just one of many, many examples where people advocate using only the normal mode for navigation.

Comment: I have `:set virtualedit=` (the default, I think) and I get similar behavior in Normal and Insert modes, so I do not think that option is what matters.

Comment: Great! `:set virtualedit=onemore` worked for me. Thanks. Also... I saw "misusing vim" argument coming, but once every a few dozens edits I end up navigating in insert mode and I don't think it's that bad. I just wanted it to act like I want it to on such occasions.